# Solr Cassandra spatial Search - Can't get any result

Tags: solr, cassandra, schema, datastax

Hi there I've been struggling for days to get any result from my spatial search queries.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong

I work with Datastax DSE 5.0.0

First I create my cassandra table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable.test (
id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
latlon varchar
city varchar,
);
```

It works fine.
Then I insert a few data:

```
insert into mytable.test (id, latlon, city) values ('1', '48.87,2.29','Paris 17' );
insert into mytable.test (id, latlon, city) values ('2', '48.86,2.29','Paris 16' );
insert into mytable.test (id, latlon, city) values ('3', '48.84,2.29','Paris 15' );
insert into mytable.test (id, latlon, city) values ('4', '48.86,2.33','Paris 1' );
```

I then change the schema xml (using Notepad++) into this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="test" version="1.1">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
      <fieldType name="coord" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate" />
      <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" />
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="id" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="city" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="latlon" stored="true" type="coord"/>
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" />
</fields>
<defaultSearchField>city</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

I send this schema to Solr using this command:

```
curl http://myhost:8983/solr/resource/mytable.test/schema.xml --data-binary @schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Then I reload Schema.xml

```
http://myhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=mytable.test
```

I guess everything should be ready now. But it's impossible for me to get any return.

```
select * from mytable.test where solr_query = '{!geofilt sfield=latlon pt=48.87,2.29 d=5}';
```

The answer is 'no result'.

Any idea of what I can do? Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

if you perform any sort of change in the schema,  you need to *reindex* the data again.

Well, that is not true for all cases, you could for instance add a new field, and you don't need to reindex, your old docs will not have that field. But when you change the type/analysis of a field, or a attribute like 'stored' etc, you need to reindex so that changes kick in.

Example:

`curl "http://10.1.2.3:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD
  &name=keyspace.table&reindex=true&deleteAll=false"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dsetool` to reindex the core, for example

```
dsetool reload_core keyspace_name.table_name reindex=true deleteAll=false
```

Note that you need to do this *once on every datacenter* if your cluster has more than one DC.

Reference DSE5.0 docs here for [reindexing in place](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/reloadingCoreCustomIndexResources.html#reloadingCoreCustomIndexResources__srchReIndx)